# Wireless connectivity on HP Stream 13-c010nr with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS from a flash drive on a HP Stream model 13-c010nr.  I have wireless connectivity when running Windows 10 on this machine, but do not get a wireless icon in 18.04.2.  How can I correct this?

I ran `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 rfkill list` as suggested.

I got back

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11 b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)  
Subsystem: Hewlett -Packard Company BCM43142 [103c:2230]  
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  RTS5229 PCI Express card reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett -Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [103c:802a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked:no
```

Comment: I had some issues with broadcoms wifi dongles, I had to compile driver myself.
Try this link:
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wifi_broadcom_bcm43xx
Maybe it can help.
BR
Juan-Carlos